# GUI settings for adding borders to images in TinyMCE editor of Connections 6

Tags: tinymce, ibm-connections

We switched from CKEditor to the new TinyMCE editor in Connections 6 CR5. This was a huge improvement. But out of the box, TinyMCE misses some of the features from CKEditor. For example setting borders on images in a way that could be handled by end users (so no manual HTML/CSS changes).

How can we add such a feature to TinyMCE, that the users get some image property dialog that allows setting image borders?

Answer (score 0):

The [image plugin has a configuration property `image_advtab`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#image_advtab), which is set to `false` by default. I tried to enable it and now we see the *advanced* tab in the image propertys, which allows setting a border (and also advanced attributes) easily:

[image]

To enable it, we need to re-add the plugin, since this allows to override it's variables. Add the following to the `externalPlugins` array in `config.js` (which is located in `${CUSTOMIZATION_DIR}/javascript/tiny/editors/connections/config.js`):

```
{
  name: "image",
  url: pluginBaseDir + "image/plugin.min.js",
  settings: {
    image_advtab: true
  }
}
```

`pluginBaseDir` is defined above the editor config:

```
  var pluginBaseDir = "/connections/resources/web/tiny.editors.connections/tinymce/plugins/";
```